# Three model association result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models that are related: Visit, Cycle and Simulator.  The relationships are as follows:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cycles
end

class Cycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :simulator, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :visit
end

class Simulator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cycles
end
```

Basically I have an action in a controller where i need to return an array of Visits but each must have a key called "simulators" that lists the simulators used on that particular visit.  A simulator can be used multiple times per visit too so the result needs deduplicating.

I've tried many methods but keep getting stuck with the best way to accomplish this.

What would the best most efficient way of achieving this be?

Neil

```
    @visitsFromDB = Visit.includes(:cycles).all
    @visits = []

    @visitsFromDB.each_with_index do |cVisit, index|
      @visit = {
        id: cVisit.id,
        date: cVisit.date,
      }

      simulators = []
      cVisit.cycles.each do |cCycle|
        simulators << Simulator.find(cCycle.simulator_id).name
      end
      simulator.uniq

      @visit[:simulators] = simulators
      @visits << @visit
    end
    @visits
```

Updated script:

```
    @visitsFromDB = Visit.includes(:simulators).all
    @visits = []

    @visitsFromDB.each_with_index do |cVisit, index|
      @visit = {
        id: cVisit.id,
        date: cVisit.date,
        park_id: cVisit.park_id
      }

      simulators = []
      cVisit.cycles.each do |cCycle|
        simulators << cCycle.simulators.map { |s| s.name }
      end
      simulators.uniq
      raise simulators.to_json

      @visit[:simulators] = simulators
      raise @visit.to_json
      @visits << @visit
    end
    raise @visits.to_json
    @visits
```

Comment: `Visit.includes(:simulators).map {|v| v.as_json(only: [:id, :date, :park_id], include: {simulators: {only: :name}})}` should do it for you. Assuming you added the relationship you stated you did in the below comment

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [has_many :through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) here. The association would allow you to establish a relationship between `Visit` and `Simulator`, where Rails would handle the heavy lifting that you're having to do in the current scenario (probably more efficiently as well)

The `Visit` model would change as follows:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cycles
  has_many :simulators, through: :cycles
end
```

This would allow us to directly fetch `simulators` associated to a `visit`. The fetching logic would then change as follows:

```
@visitsFromDB = Visit.includes(:simulators).all
# Now @visitsFromDB.first.simulators would give us the simulators associated with the first visit
```

Comment: minor note "without an additional DB call" is not technically correct as there will be 2 db calls involved. If you want these all loaded in a single query it would be `includes(:simulators).references(:simulators)`

Comment: @anuj-khandelwal Thanks for that.  I've added that relationship and tweaked my script but when i check the output i see the simulators key but it's empty every time?  Any ideas?

Comment: How're you populating simulators? By using `.includes`, you won't get the simulators in the visit record itself (like you'd get column values of the visit record). You'll have to use `visit.simulators` to get simulators associated with the visit. The advantage of `includes` is, when you run `visit.simulators`, the simulators are already in memory and do not need a call to the DB for each visit's `visit.simulators`